# Pasting Multi-Line PowerShell script works in PowerShell ISE but Fails in PowerShell Console

Tags: powershell

When pasting a multi-line script into PowerShell ISE it seems to execute the entire script block at once.

Output from PowerShell ISE

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           



PS C:\> if ($true) {
 Write-Output "yes"
}
else {
 Write-Output "no"
}
yes

PS C:\>
```

When pasting a multi-line script into PowerShell Console, it seems to try to execute Line-By-Line?

Output from PowerShell Console

```
C:\> $PSVersionTable                                                                                                    
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


C:\> if ($true) {
>>  Write-Output "yes"
>> }                                                                                                                    yes
C:\> else {
>>  Write-Output "no"
>> }                                                                                                                    else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ else {
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

C:\>
```

The behaviour I'm expecting from PowerShell Console is the same as the behaviour in PowerShell ISE, it should know that `else` is a part of the `if` statement.

I don't remember this ever acting that way. What is causing this behaviour to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is failing because the `else {` is on a different line than the `}` above it. either add a backtick to indicate it's spreading to the next line or remove the carriage return before `else`:

```
if ($true) {
  Write-Output "yes"
} else {
  Write-Output "no"
}
```

Comment: interesting, I also noticed you can put else on a new line if you put the if-statement inside a function.

Comment: One thing, I tested out what you're saying and I found that \ doesn't work. In my case it was the ` that lets you indicate it's spreading to the next line.

Comment: Thanks, it won't let me quote the backtick as far as I can tell since it is used to created the code styles.